# how to use "Boxed pointer of type GstBuffer"

Tags: gstreamer, glib

The ubiquitous glib supports a type called "boxed" which can contain other types, like a boxed structure or a boxed point. This boxed type provides a copy and a free routine that is specific to what is contained in the box.

The documentation for the Gnome boxed types provides no information on how to create a specific type of boxed type and I am unable to find any examples on how to use this type.

Question: do I have to "register" every box type I need using the routine:   g_boxed_type_register_static()   ?

Question: is there any example code for creating a "boxed point of type GstBuffer"?

I know how to use the GStreamer GstBuffer but not sure how to use it in this particular situation.

Thanks,
-Andres

Comment: Your question isn't really clear; are you trying to use GstBuffer and is it already a boxed type? Or are you trying to create a new boxed type?

Comment: The reason why my question is not clear is because I was very confused. Turns out, GstBuffer *is* a boxed object so a "boxed pointer of type GstBuffer" is just a pointer to a GstBuffer. My code kept failing so I figured it was because I had the type wrong, but the failure was because of improper reference counting on my part. Sometimes the documentation on GStreamer is confusing to me--and my first language *is* English!  :-)